# Bootstrap Adding white block in front of background color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use bootstrap and make a section look like this: [What it's supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE8UI.png)

The problem I have is the white block in the middle on top of the green background. If I add an extra class to the outermost div (padding), nothing shows up, but if I add it to any of the other divs it only encompasses the photo (not there sorry) and the text instead of 100% height of the padding. I've tried z-index: 999 with width of 80% and height 100%, but it kinda screws up the background.

I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="padding attractionPad">
        <div class="container attractionContainer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src ="img2.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ul class="attraction">
                        <li><h3>Ninja Course</h3></li>
                        <li><h3>Indoor Bounce Arena</h3></li>
                        <li><h3>Mechanical Wipeout Challenge</h3></li>
                        <li><h3>Ziplining Fun</h3></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    background-color: #EE870D;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.padding{
    padding: 80px 0;
}
.padding img{
    width:100%;
}
.attractionPad{
    background-color: #8FBA51;
}
.attraction{
    color:blue;
    list-style:none;
}
.events li, .attraction li{
    margin: 10px 0 50px 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4agbp8tf/2/

Comment: does `.attractionContainer{ background: #fff }` help?

Comment: I've tried that, but all it does is kinda pads the picture + words. It'll never get to 100% of the background height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as comment. you need to add this css on .attractionContainer , because this container is containing your content (row).

if you want the "What it's supposed to look like".
you need to remove padding css

```css
html,body{
 background-color: #EE870D;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
.padding{
 padding: 0px ;
}
/* remove class or this css */
.padding img{
 width:100%;
}
.attractionPad{
 background-color: #8FBA51;
}
.attraction{
 color:blue;
 list-style:none;
}
.events li, .attraction li{
 margin: 10px 0 50px 0;
}
.attractionContainer{
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Oh my. I didn't see that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

for a full-page responsive, centered behavior, the code below:

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #EE870D;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.padding {
  padding: 80px 0;
}

.padding img {
  width: 100%;
}

.attractionPad {
  background-color: #8FBA51;
}

.attraction {
  color: blue;
  list-style: none;
}

.events li,
.attraction li {
  margin: 10px 0 50px 0;
}

.attractionContainer {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class=" attractionPad">
  <div class="container attractionContainer d-flex">
    <div class="row align-self-center">
      <div class="col-sm-6 ">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <ul class="attraction">
          <li>
            <h3>Ninja Course</h3>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h3>Indoor Bounce Arena</h3>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h3>Mechanical Wipeout Challenge</h3>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h3>Ziplining Fun</h3>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```